# Use of unassigned local variable?

Tags: c#

Visual Studio keeps saying `Use of unassigned variable` for `iVal` and `iNumber`. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

This is designed to be a code to ask the user to keep entering integers and adding them up until the user wants to stop.  The sum of the integers is then displayed on the console.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace AddFive
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           int iNumber;
           int iVal;
           int iTotal = 0;

            while (iVal > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter number " + iNumber);
                iVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                iTotal = iTotal + iVal;
            }

            if (iNumber <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Total = " + iTotal);
                iVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                iTotal = iTotal + iVal;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Total = " + iTotal);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you compare the lines  iTotal and iNumber and iVal the difference would be easy to spot I guess...

Answer (score 7):

Assign values to those variables. You need to assign values to local variables before using them

```
    int iNumber = 0;
    int iVal = 0;
```

when you wrote `while (iVal > 0)`, the value of `iVal` has not been set

You can get away with that only with instance/class variable, as they are initialized to default value

```
public class Program
{
    int i; //this was not implicitly initialized to zero (0)

    public Program()
    {
        int j; //need to initialize this before use

        Console.Write(j);  //this throws "Use of unassigned variable" error
        Console.Write(i);  //this prints 0, the default value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio is correct, you're trying to reference an uninitialized variable.

Try this:

```
 int iNumber = 0;
 int iVal = 0;
```

This way, your are initializing the variables to an initial value of 0.
The original problem occurs on these lines:

`while (iVal > 0)`
and
`if (iNumber <= 0)`

In which you try to access the variables before giving them a value.

Answer (score 3):

In C# you must assign value to variable before use it.

e.g.

```
 int iNumber = 0;
 int iVal = 0;
```

Comment: Actually you don't HAVE TO the author only was getting a warning not a compiler error. They could ignore the warning considering the default value of an `integer` is `0`.

Comment: @Ramhound in this example you received two errors, not warnings.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize `iNumber` and `iVal`. Think about what value they will have the first time through the `while` loop, in your current code.

Answer (score 3):

Your iVal parameter is unassigned in your while loop. you need to give is a value when you initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is as noted in several places that you do not assign a value to iNumber or iVal before you use them the first time (in your while statements). In this particular case it's benign and assigning the default value what change a thing. The error is though appropriate. Historically unassigned variables have been a headache in languages that do allow the use of unassigned variables. Especially in languages that do not initialize a storage location to default value. C# does initialize to a default value in this case but it might still lead to hard to find bugs. The compiler is smart enough to check the path the code takes before reaching a particular use of a local and if you can get there with out assigning a value it will complain. This can help in complex code where the code when read sequentially leads you to think that the local has been assigned but in fact due to conditional logic it's not