# Variable is used before its assignd a value?

Tags: vb.net, variables

Can someone explain wy i get this error becase i have no idee

[image: Varibale not used]

Srry image is good now pleas explain wy i get this error

LOL i cant explain this thats wy i use image pleas save to desktop and open than 
I just think its weird so i use image if you dont whanne see the weird error oke hope somone else will

Tanx for -4 Rep you diddent read my comment so i cant give anyone here a + becase you guys only look at error i whanted explanation wy the value is something in the elseif and nothing in the if i dident ask for a solution but an explantion about it

Comment: Don't post just images but code.

Comment: It would help if you posted the code causing this error. Having said that, it is rather clear - you are using a variable before you have assigned a value to it. What about that statement do you not understand?

Comment: Do you really expect us to be able to read any of that? POST YOUR CODE NOT AN IMAGE.

Answer (score 1):

All it means is `endhours1` and some other variables were not assigned values and you were trying to call `.Replace` on it

To make use of any local variable you must first assign a value/default value to it. What will `.Replace` replace when there is no value in the variable?

Here is a [duplicate of your question and is well answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219462/use-of-unassigned-local-variable/13219477#13219477)

If those variables were not used, the compiler won't complain.

On the line where you have

```
Dim regel, onderwerp, body, reminder... etc
```

Give them an initial/default value or use Nullable types

```
Dim regel As Integer = 0
Dim onderwerp As String = ""
Dim body As String = ""
```

Comment: oke dont read my edit Never mind de question you can delete it i can do work arround but i dont whant to.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that the variables were unassigned when they were used. It's not a runtime error, it's a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it acutally never could happen, the compiler can't determine that the variables always are assigned a value.

Assign a value to the variables in the beginning, so that the compiler doesn't think that they are unassigned.

(In later versions of VB the compiler warns you when you use variables that could possibly be unassigned. Earlier versions just assigned a zero/Nothing value to all variables, and didn't warn you.)

Comment: Oke but if i run the code in the if from the if stament onderwerp = nothing and in the else if its something HOW???

Comment: @AntoonVs: An unassigned variable doesn't contain `Nothing`, it doesn't have a value at all. You can't check for the value `Nothing` because that would be using the variable before the compiler knows that it has surely been assigned a value. If you want the value to be `Nothing` if you don't assign anything else to it, assign `Nothing` to it in the beginning.